# Visual Studio Code highlight selection on minimap (not scrollbar)

Tags: visual-studio-code, scrollbar, selection, highlight

Is there a way to highlight all matches position on the vsc's minimap when double click a word in the editor?

I have tried *[select highlight in minimap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mde.select-highlight-minimap)*, but it renders the highlight on the scrollbar instead of the minimap as figer 1.

Does anyone know a way to achieve my requirements, thanks!

There is an extension of visual studio named *[RockMargin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=K1tty.RockMargin)* as figure 2.

[image]
Figure 1.

[image]
Figure 2.

Update: the author of extension *select highlight in minimap* replied it's not possible to edit the minimap rendering for the moment(202004). Hope it can be realized in the future T_T.

Comment: Did you try the answer in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

This is the one you are looking for:

`"minimap.selectionOccurrenceHighlight": "#ff0000",`

You can try these in your `colorCustomiztions` in settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "minimap.selectionOccurrenceHighlight": "#ff0000",

  "minimap.selectionHighlight": "#bbff00",
  "minimap.findMatchHighlight": "#ff0000",
  "minimap.warningHighlight": "#ff0000"
}
```

Definitely reload vscode after making any changes to `colorCustomiztions`.  I get some funky behaviour if I don't do that.